# How to hide empty table cells in pdf?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have developed a pdf report but it contains some empty cells. how can I hide this empty cells? My o/p is,

[image]

Here I want to remove/hide the empty cells. When you read this you may think why he cannot declare table colomn count as his need. But here situation is different, my table cells fills as per my query result. ie, sometimes there will not be any empty cells...depends up on my query result. The way I create it,

```
 PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(30);
 table1.TotalWidth = 800f;//table size
 table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
 table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("80", font1)));
 table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
 table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("85", font1)));
 table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
 table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("85", font1))  );
 table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
 table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("85", font1)));
 table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
 table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("85", font1)) );
 table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
 table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("" + lblSub4.Text "",font1)));
 table.CompleteRow();
 doc.Add(table);
```

This code I added only to know how I created pdf table.just a sample one it is

Comment: how You generate Your pdf at all?... using some report tool, iTextSharp or somehow else? update Your question with some code, please.

Comment: @ nelek, yes I am using itextsharp.

Comment: that's better :) but, note that in question because other.

Comment: again new question: how You populate `PdfPTable`, `PdfPCell`, etc? From `GridView`, `DataTable`, ...? You can hide entire `column` but specific `cell`, I think You can't.

Comment: @ nelek, I populated pdftable using Gridview? how can I hide entire column?

Comment: Why just not set columns in `PdfPTable` like this `PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(GridView.Columns.Count-1);` and `PdfPTable` will be generated with number of `columns` in `GridView`?  btw. My bad, You can't hide `column` but can avoid. There is some example : http://stackoverflow.com/a/24716922/3279496

Comment: @nelek ,hmmm..let me try once..ur above example

Comment: This is link for one of mine past answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31450142/3279496 (**under Update#2** it's in vb, sorry) You only have to change `Dim tbl As New PdfPTable(7)` with `Dim tbl As New PdfPTable(gvUsers.Columns.Count - 1)` and ignore `SetWidths` by that example. if that's work for You I can post entire solution like anwser.